# how to 'break' out of an if loop in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

When I use `break` in an if loop in bash it tells me its not valid for bash, what can I use instead?

The use case is, the user is asked a question and if he answers 'no', the script should skip to the next section.

```
if [[ $ans1_1 = "y" ]]; then
    fedoraDeps
elif [[ $ans1_1 = "n" ]]; then
    break
else
    echo "Answer 'y' or 'n' "
fi
```

Comment: Yes it would be usefull to not check all conditions of the "if elif ..elif else fi" pattern in some cases, for example when conditions are using the file-system.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`if` statements are not "loops", so it doesn't make sense to break out of them. If you want one of your blocks to be a no-op, you can use the built-in `:` command, which simply does nothing:

```
if [[ $ans1_1 = y ]]; then
    fedoraDeps
elif [[ $ans1_1 = n ]]; then
    :
else
    echo "Answer 'y' or 'n'"
fi
```

Comment: What make sense is to avoid testing all conditions of an if then elif elif ... fi construct in some conditions, like when conditions are calling the file-system.

Answer (score 4):

For this example, I think it makes more sense to use `case`.

```
case $ans1_1 in
    y)fedoraDeps;;
    n);;
    *) echo "Answer 'y' or 'n'";;
esac
```

From `man bash`:

> If the ;; operator is used, no subsequent matches are attempted after the first pattern match.

Comment: This looks cleaner and easier to maintain. I'll update my script to use cases instead. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I agree that case is probably best.  But you should probably cast to upper/lower case either way.  For the way you had it:

```
if [[ ${ans1_1,,} = "y" ]]; then
   fedoraDeps
elif [[ ${ans1_1,,} = "n" ]]; then
   :
else
   echo "Answer 'y' or 'n' "
fi
```

Or, if you wanted uppercase ${ans1_1^^}

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an ideal case for the `select` command:

```
PS3="Please make a selection   >"
select foo in 'y' 'n'; do
    case $foo in
        'Y')
            fedoraDeps
            ;;
        'y')
            fedoraDeps
            ;;
        'n')
            break
            ;;
     esac
done
```

Comment: But doesn't that mean that instead of a normal `y`/`n` input, the user will instead have to enter `1` for yes and `2` for no? That seems needlessly complicated for this purpose.

Comment: In fairnesss, `1` or `2` is no more or less complicated than `y` or `n`, but if the goal is to keep asking until a valid selection is made, `select` is one of the best tools for the job.

Comment: Being presented with `1) y` and `2) n`, and having to type `1` or `2` rather than `y` or `n`, is certainly more complicated just simply typing `y`/`n`. I don't see how you can feel otherwise.

Comment: `break` makes only sense in **loops**... `if` and `case` are no loops. use `:` (does nothing) instead or at `case` you can resp. should simply remove the `break`-line.

Comment: btw: as @Coder-guy already briefly mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28091822/2351568), i would use `case "${foo,,}" in` to prevent having to maintain 2 identical cases.