# else part not working in bash while read loop

Tags: bash, while-loop

In bash coding,

What to do is that if the grep size is less than 800MB i want to ignore but if grep size is more than 800MB, i want to print that path in file xyz/symlinks_paths.txt. but problem coming in else statement. Can you help me, i want to print that path whose size is more than 800MB in xyz/size_list.txt file. Also, line3 is a directory path.

```
while
    read -r line3
        do
            if [[ "ls -lh $line3 | grep zzz.exe | grep '[8-9][0-9][0-9][MG]'" = " " ]] 
                then break
                else line3 >> xyz/size_list.txt
            fi
        done < xyz/symlinks_paths.txt
```

Comment: `break` breaks out of the loop

Comment: No, the error says, line3 is a directory OR line3 command not found, that means after break it is in if loop only.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011010/how-to-break-out-of-an-if-loop-in-bash

Comment: Maybe you should try with `find`, which lists all your symlinks and can even give you the information on sizes for found files.

Comment: No Stefan, i dont want to use find command, because i have to run this on huge database, which will take days on find.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't [parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

On the other hand, you're exiting your while-loop with the `break` statement. Maybe you can negate your `if`-condition, so that you can put your `else`-Part into the `then` part.

What were you trying to achieve by this line:

```
line3 >> xyz/size_list.txt
```

Do you want to append the contents of ${line3} into the file? Than this should work:

```
echo "${line3}" >> xyz/size_list.txt
```

Comment: how to negate this if loop?

Comment: With a !. See for example this answer to [Negate if condition in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26475397/2768231).

Answer (score 1):

Imho, it's better (and more readable) to do like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

while
    read -r line3
        do
            #819200 kbytes = 800 Mbytes. Echo in file if the size greater or equal
            if [ $(du -s "${line3}/zzz.exe" | awk '{print $1}') -ge 819200 ]
            then 
                echo "${line3}" >> xyz/size_list.txt
            fi
        done < xyz/symlinks_paths.txt
```

Comment: Using ${line3} , still says that line3 is a directory. :(

Comment: @Pompy well..can you show me that variable value in your code?

Comment: /prj/pika/BMX/pikatree/1504729073xz-dir/pulser

Comment: sorry viktor, i forgot the echo. my bad. :)